# Which Perl module would you recommend for sending and getting e-mail?

Tags: perl, email, smtp, module, imap

I am searching a Perl module to write (SMTP) and read (IMAP) e-mails. Which module out of the bunch would you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME::Lite) is the most widely used and stable module around for sending e-mails. It supports sendmail and SMTP sending methods.

For IMAP, it depends on how low-level your needs are, but [Net::IMAP::Client](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::IMAP::Client) is simple to use and should suit most needs.

Comment: MIME::Lite is not recommended by current maintainer.

Answer (score 9):

For email sending, [Email::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart) is pretty neat.

Answer (score 4):

For sending emails I've been a long (time || in the tooth) user of [`MIME::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MIME-Lite/) and have many scripts/programs that use it.

However recently I've been using [`Email::Stuff`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-Stuff/) and would highly recommend looking at it.

For Perl email information in general then the [`Perl Email Project`](http://emailproject.perl.org/) would be a good resource but its currently under *reconstruction*.

In lieu of this I recommend you keep an eye on [Ricardo Signes blog](http://rjbs.manxome.org/journal) (rjbs is the core maintainer of the Perl Email Project and pretty much ubiquitous with everything email in Perl!).

Here are a few useful links from [rjbs](http://rjbs.manxome.org/) recent [advent calendar](http://advent.rjbs.manxome.org/):

- [MIME, Dreaming of a White Christmas](http://advent.rjbs.manxome.org/2009-12-10.html)
- [E-mail Made Simple](http://advent.rjbs.manxome.org/2009-12-12.html)
- [Sending Email Simply](http://advent.rjbs.manxome.org/2009-12-24.html)

/I3az/

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Mail::Sendmail](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mail::Sendmail) in the past, and it's worked great.  Just need Perl and a network connection.